# My site can be opened by Chrome, but not by IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, ssl, cross-browser, browser-security

I have built [this site](https://www.funfun.io). It works perfectly in Chrome, whereas I cannot open it in Internet Explorer 11. It shows a blank page.

When I open the Developer Tools by `F12`, there is no error shown in the console.

Does anyone know where is the problem?

**Edit 1:**

I changed several machines and finally could see the error in the console: [console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VYwq.png). as @MrNew commented, it is `Unable to get property 'postMessage' of undefined or null reference`.

Does anyone know how to fix this? is it because of the compatibility of angularjs and IE 11?

Comment: It will be difficult to troubleshoot your entire site.  There are other issues with running angularjs on IE11, search stackoverflow for similar issues using whichever libraries you are using.

Comment: The problem is, without any error in the console, I even don't know what to troubleshoot... Which version of IE works well with angularjs?

Comment: There is a console log error :) just refresh the page while dev tool is open. Error `Unable to get property 'postMessage' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Indeed, it is this message, do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

`if ($window.opener === null)` is not enough in IE 11, we should check `if (($window.opener === null) || ($window.opener === undefined))`.

So there is nothing to do with angularjs.